# Decimal Sum in node js

Tags: node.js, v8

Adding 2 numbers in nodejs with 2 decimal places doesn't leads to unexpected results
The following code results in

```
console.log(34.02 + 1378.12);
```

> 1412.1399999999999

But the expected result is

> 1412.14

Answer (score 0):

You can use toFixed(2).

```
console.log((34.02 + 1378.12).toFixed(2));
```